# how maven-install-plugin work with pom configure to install some jars one time

Tags: java, maven

when I install one jar,the pom like

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
   <configuration>
      <groupId>org.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>oraclejdbc</artifactId>
      <version>14</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <file>${basedir}/libs/ojdbc14.jar</file>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>install-jar-lib</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>install-file</goal>
         </goals>
         <phase>validate</phase>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

then

```
 mvn install:install-file
```

it works,but I want install some jars not only one,so I edit the pom like

```
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-artifacts.1</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>org.oracle</groupId>
                            <artifactId>oraclejdbc</artifactId>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <version>14</version>
                            <file>${basedir}/libs/ojdbc14.jar</file>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-artifacts.2</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${basedir}/libs/sqljdbc4.jar</file>
                            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <artifactId>sqljdbc</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
              </executions>
     </plugin>
```

then

```
mvn install:install-file
```

But,the console show

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file (default-cli) on project core: The parameters 'file' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]

what should I do? thanks!

Comment: In my case `<generatePom>true</generatePom>` inside configuration part worked!

Answer (score 1):

On executing from command line the goal requires the parameter `file` which could be provided as:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=.../libs/ojdbc14.jar
```

Or using the same configuration as specified in your `pom.xml` you can simply execute

```
mvn install
```

---

Also, note the artifactId in one of your execution doesn't seem valid

```
<file>${basedir}/libs/sqljdbc4.jar</file>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<artifactId>sqljdbc</artifactId> <!--this might be sqljdbc4-->
```

and when you don't have POM for 3rd party artifacts, you can follow [generic pom generation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/generic-pom-generation.html) and make use of

```
mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar \
                          -DgroupId=your.groupId \
                          -DartifactId=your-artifactId \
                          -Dversion=version \
                          -Dpackaging=jar \
                          -DgeneratePom=true
```

Comment: But I have some jars , -Dfile can write more than one jar ?

Comment: I try mvn install but get [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc:jar is missing. @ com.enation.app.javashop:core:[unknown-version], D:\javashop_sts\javashop\core\pom.xml, line 522, column 15

Comment: @freeMeng Your `<dependency>` on `<artifactId>sqljdbc</artifactId>` needs to have some `<version></version>`

Comment: After add version,I try mvn install but also get [ERROR] The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc:jar:1.0,

Comment: @freeMeng See the update on the answer. The jar and artifact name used by you doesn't seem correct IMO. I would rather investigate the jar in use and its attributes before specifying them in the pom.xml configuration.

Comment: I don't have POM for 3rd party artifacts so I use maven-install-plugin,but now the problem is install one jar,it's ok ,add two jar  it's valid.

Comment: @freeMeng the 2nd jar that you are adding is the cause, you should invest some time in getting to generate pom for it maybe.

Comment: @ nullpointer Thanks your answer,I just want to generate pom for my jars at one time.